# Javascript replace code line including doc comment

Tags: javascript, regex, regexp-replace

I'm using AutoRest to generate client code. With AutoRest you can add custom transformation scripts to alter the generated code.

I'm trying to remove two interface properties from the code that is generated by  using a Javascript regex replace. But I can't figure out what the correct regex is for this.

This is a piece of the code that I need to alter:

```cs
// <auto-generated>
// Code generated by Microsoft (R) AutoRest Code Generator.
// Changes may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if the code is
// regenerated.
// </auto-generated>

namespace Test.AcmeWeb.Repositories.Test.Products
{
    using Microsoft.Rest;
    using Models;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    /// <summary>
    /// Acme Products API
    /// </summary>
    public partial interface IApiProducts : System.IDisposable
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The base URI of the service.
        /// </summary>
        System.Uri BaseUri { get; set; }
          
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets json serialization settings.
        /// </summary>
        JsonSerializerSettings SerializationSettings { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets json deserialization settings.
        /// </summary>
        JsonSerializerSettings DeserializationSettings { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// CreateAppointment
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Creates an appointment, given a timeslot id, order id and remark,
        /// wrapped in a requestmodel.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <param name='label'>
        /// Possible values include: 'default', 'Acme'
        /// </param>
        /// <param name='body'>
        /// </param>
        /// <param name='customHeaders'>
        /// The headers that will be added to request.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name='cancellationToken'>
        /// The cancellation token.
        /// </param>
        Task<HttpOperationResponse<ErrorResponse>> ApiProductsAppointmentsCreateAppointmentPUTWithHttpMessagesAsync(string label, RequestDataAppointmentRequestModel body = default(RequestDataAppointmentRequestModel), Dictionary<string, List<string>> customHeaders = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
```

I specifically want to remove the following two lines from this code (including the comments):

```cs
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets json serialization settings.
        /// </summary>
        JsonSerializerSettings SerializationSettings { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets json deserialization settings.
        /// </summary>
        JsonSerializerSettings DeserializationSettings { get; }
```

It is fine for me to run two separate regex replace calls to replace it one at a time. My regex currently looks like this for the first line, including the comment.

```
\/\/\/ <summary>\r\n[\s]+\/\/\/Gets or sets json serialization[^]+JsonSerializerSettings SerializationSettings { get; }
```

But unfortunately this doesn't seem to match any pattern.

How do I have to alter my regex to make this work?

Live demo can be found here: https://regexr.com/5eleb

Comment: Try it like this https://regex101.com/r/sYKVjy/1 `\/\/\/ <summary>.*\r?\n.*Gets or sets json (?:de)?serialization.*\r?\n.*\/\/\/ <\/summary>\r?\n.*JsonSerializerSettings (?:De)?[sS]erializationSettings { get; }\s*`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is serialization and deserialization in the text and you can make the `\r` optional in `\r\n`

To match both parts, you might use

```
\/\/\/ <summary>\r?\n[^\S\r\n]*\/\/\/ Gets or sets json (?:de)?serialization.*\r?\n[^\S\r\n]*\/\/\/ <\/summary>\r?\n[^\S\r\n]*JsonSerializerSettings (?:De)?[sS]erializationSettings { get; }\s*
```

**Explanation**

- `\/\/\/ <summary>\r?\n` Match the start of the summary part
- `[^\S\r\n]*\/\/\/`  Match optional whitespace chars without a newline and `///`
- `Gets or sets json (?:de)?serialization.*\r?\n` Match the text with optional `de` and the rest of the line including a newline
- `[^\S\r\n]*\/\/\/ <\/summary>\r?\n` Match optional whitespace chars, `///` and the last summary part including a newline
- `[^\S\r\n]*JsonSerializerSettings`  Match optional whitespace chars followed by `JsonSerializerSettings` which is in both parts
- `(?:De)?[sS]erializationSettings { get; }\s*` Match optional `De`, then an upper or lowercase `s` followed by `erializationSettings` and the rest of the line. The `\s*` will match trailing whitespace chars, including newlines

In the replacement use an empty string.

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p2T2iY/1)

---

You could also match it as one block, but in the pattern that you tried it does not take the closing summary part into account. You would also have to make the `[^]+?` non greedy to prevent over matching.

```
\/\/\/ <summary>\r?\n[\s]+\/\/\/ Gets or sets json (?:de)?serialization[^]+?JsonSerializerSettings (?:De)?[sS]erializationSettings { get; }
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eM88vx/1)